# Joomla article 3.X - Hot to define a img article for a external run

Tags: database, joomla, external, article

I am using (improperly) a call to an external db where, based on the title of the article (which is empty) it gives me back some values ​​which I then expose.

The problem is that being the article composed only by the title and when I go to use the Joomla modules, they don't see the values ​​that I extract from db.

In practice, at each external call, I would like to re-define the parameters of that view:

```
introtext
text
img
```

PHp code:

```
<?php

$option = JRequest::getCmd('option');
$view = JRequest::getCmd('view');
if ($option=="com_content" && $view=="article") {
    $ids = explode(':',JRequest::getString('id'));
    $article_id = $ids[0];
    $article =& JTable::getInstance("content");
    $article->load($article_id);
    $nome_micio =  $article->get("title");



}

echo $nome_micio;

$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$gatto = $db->setQuery("SELECT * FROM #__gatti WHERE nome = '$nome_micio' and deceduto = 'No'")->loadObject();


?>
```

I need something like

```
define ($article->introtext) = $gatto->textonquerydb
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you be more specific and possibly add some code and explain where your code lives (module? component? template? plugin?).

Comment: Hi, I'm using a pure php code into an article. Take a look to the answer now. ;) Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Please post your Joomla questions at [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.

Comment: sorry you need to move your answer, post the new url here - and while you're at it, add the relative path where you put your code, I still haven't figured it out - as Joomla does NOT allow you to put php code in your article it must be somewhere else.

Comment: Yes you can insert php code in article using plugin {sourcerer} ;-)

Comment: I would guess that query contains a SQL injection vulnerability. Can you use parameter binding in Joomla instead?